# After recent update vs code transpiling stopped working: tsc is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, transpiler

The title says all, anyway, after update yesterday visual code studio is not transpiling ts files to js saying tsc is not recognized asa external or internal command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings, set the location of the typescript sdk

The setting can now take absolute and relative paths.

I have typescript installed locally in my projects, so my stting looks like

```
 {
     "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
 }
```

I use VSCode 0.10.5 and TS 1.7.5 which are the latest at time of writing

Comment: Menu Code -> Preferences