# How to install and run Typescript locally in npm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I want to install and run Typescript (i.e. no global dependencies).

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I then run:

```
npm install
npm run tsc
```

However when I run the second command I get sooo many errors it cannot display all it. Most of it is like the following:

```
../foo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(5015,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'webkitTransformOrigin'.
../foo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(5016,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'webkitTransformStyle'.
../foo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(5017,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'webkitTransition'.
../foo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(5018,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'webkitTransitionDelay'.
../foo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(5019,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'webkitTransitionDuration'.
../foo/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(5020,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'webkitTransitionProperty'.
```

In npm-debug.log I get:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'tsc' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.2
3 info using node@v5.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretsc', 'tsc', 'posttsc' ]
5 info lifecycle foo@1.0.0~pretsc: foo@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle foo@1.0.0~pretsc: no script for pretsc, continuing
7 info lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: foo@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/vagrant/foo/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
10 verbose lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: CWD: /home/vagrant/foo
11 silly lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: Args: [ '-c', 'tsc' ]
12 silly lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle foo@1.0.0~tsc: Failed to exec tsc script
14 verbose stack Error: foo@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid foo@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/foo
17 error Linux 3.13.0-88-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "tsc"
19 error node v5.12.0
20 error npm  v3.10.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error foo@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the foo@1.0.0 tsc script 'tsc'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the foo package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs foo
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls foo
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Note that removing the package and then installing typescript globally solves the problem. However if I then use npm install to install the local packages again, it reintroduces the problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To install TypeScript local in project as a development dependency you can use `--save-dev` key

```
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

It's also writes the typescript into your `package.json`

You also need to have a `tsconfig.json` file. For example

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".npm"
  ]
}
```

For more information about the tsconfig you can see here http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: how is that any different what I did in my `package.json`. All that does is install type script and save it in my dependencies. It's also a dev dependency (not a normal dependency) so it should be `npm install --dev-save`

Comment: @YahyaUddin are you have a `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: I tried different ways to cause the error you have provided in your question or something like that, but I did not succeed

Comment: This solution seem to work for now. However note that you are not allows to use `files` and `exclude` at the same time according to: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

Thanks for your help. I'll give an update if this works!

Comment: @YahyaUddin You mean it https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md#exclude? Thank you, I'm I will consider it for the future

Comment: When attempting to repeat the issue yourself, did you try it without the "exclude" part of the tsconfig

Comment: @YahyaUddin When I attempting to repeat the issue myself, I use `exclude` in tsconfig. As in my answer

Comment: That's why you didn't get the problem. Having the `exclude` fixes the issue!

Answer (score 106):

It took me a while to figure out the solution to this problem - it's in the original question. You need to have a `script` that calls `tsc` in your `package.json` file so that you can run:

```
npm run tsc
```

Include `--` before you pass in options (or just include them in the script):

```
npm run tsc -- -v
```

Here's an example `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hard issue to google! Works for cli packages that suggest you install it globally but only want them locally, thanks!

Comment: thanks.,, i have been searching for solution and your answer works for me.

Comment: Why would you want to install a development tool under `"dependencies"` instead of `"devDependencies"`?

Comment: And for whom is interested on what -- is about:
"--" Indicates the end of node options. Pass the rest of the arguments to the script. If no script filename or eval/print script is supplied prior to this, then the next argument will be used as a script filename.

Answer (score 96):

As of npm 5.2.0 you no longer need an entry in the `scripts` section of `package.json`. You can now run the compiler with [npx](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner):

```
npx tsc
```

...and you don't have to update package.json with a new script every time you want to compile with different arguments.

Comment: This is a brilliant suggestion. Saved me a ton of time

Comment: `npx tsc` is definitely the way to go if you need a lightweight, minimal-config, local project solution. It can even be used without `npm i` for infrequently run commands, though without running `npm i` first, `npx` will need to install the necessary packages into a temp folder each time. More info on `npx` here: https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b

Comment: This was the answer for me!

Comment: This is the way also to check for the version, that indeed will match the one in the package.json 'npx tsc --version'

Answer (score 21):

You need to tell npm that "tsc" exists as a local project package (via the "scripts" property in your package.json) and then run it via `npm run tsc`. To do that (at least on Mac) I had to add the path for the actual compiler within the package, like this

```
{
  "name": "foo"
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.3.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

After that you can run any TypeScript command like `npm run tsc -- --init` (the arguments come after the first `--`).

Comment: If you execute tsc from the root directory of your repo (where you have your node_modules), this is not necessary, you should be able to run tsc without an additional script. But when you have a monorepo with nested package.json files and want to run tsc there without installing typescript in the child-repo-directory, this is very useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can now use [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), which makes your life as simple as

```
npm install -D ts-node
npm install -D typescript

ts-node script.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

`tsc` requires a config file or .ts(x) files to compile.

To solve both of your issues, create a file called `tsconfig.json` with the following contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Also, modify your npm run with this

```
tsc --config /path/to/a/tsconfig.json
```

Comment: I only needed the exclude part for it to work. You also don't need to use `-- config` parameter as typescript looks there automatically provided its at the root of your project.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 1):

Note if you are using `typings` do the following:

```
rm -r typings
typings install
```

If your doing the angular 2 tutorial use this:

```
rm -r typings
npm run postinstall
npm start
```

if the `postinstall` command dosen't work, try installing typings globally like so:

```
npm install -g typings
```

you can also try the following as opposed to postinstall:

```
typings install
```

and you should have this issue fixed!

Answer (score 1):

To install and run **TypeScript** locally in your npm project, follow these steps:

1. **Initialize Your Project**:
   If you haven't already, create a new npm project or navigate to an existing one.
2. **install TypeScript** as a **development dependency** using the following command:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev typescript
   ```
3. **Create a tsconfig.json File**:
   In your project directory, run:

   ```bash
   npx tsc --init
   ```

   - This will generate a `tsconfig.json` file with default settings. You can modify this file to suit your project's needs.
4. Add **tsc script** to your `package.json` file:

   ```json
   {
     "name": "myproject",
     "scripts": {
       "tsc": "tsc"
     },
     // ... other properties
   }
   ```
5. **Write TypeScript Code**:

   - Create a `.ts` file (e.g., `app.ts`) in your project folder.
   - Write your TypeScript code in this file.
6. Run TypeScript in your project using:

   ```
   npm run tsc
   ```
7. **Run Your JavaScript Code**:
   You can run the JavaScript code using `node`. For example:

   ```bash
   node app.js
   ```

Make sure you have the latest version of **Node** and **npm** installed.