# 'tsc command not found' in compiling typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc

I want to install typescript, so I used the following command:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and test `tsc --version`, but it just show 'tsc command not found'. I have tried many ways as suggested in stackoverflow, github and other sites. but it doesn't work. How could I know typescript is installed and where it is.

my OS is Unix, OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, 
   node version is 4.4.3, 
   npm version is 3.10.5

Comment: Most likely you have a problem with your node/npm setup; for example, the relevant npm directory is not on your path. Where typescript is installed depends on your environment, but you could start with `npm list -g`. Or try `npm config get prefix` (your packages will normally be in the `bin` directory under this). Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages).

Comment: Thanks you , I got it. I forgot to export prefix path.

Comment: You can also check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63104672/2404470)

Comment: I got it working switching to yarn

Comment: in my case i had two windows users and i forgot i need to add it to the path

Comment: In my case I needed to do `node_modules/.bin/tsc --version` ✍

Answer (score 278, accepted):

A few tips in order

- restart the terminal
- restart the machine
- reinstall nodejs + then run `npm install typescript -g`

If it still doesn't work run `npm config get prefix` to see where npm install -g is putting files (append `bin` to the output) and make sure that they are in the path (the node js setup does this. Maybe you forgot to tick that option).

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Sure , I forgot to assign path `export PATH=/prefix'sPath/bin:$PATH' and  (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)  also this site suggest like this. I used a whole day for this :).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46783952/495157 - This answer is more informative - especially if you do Angular/Ionic development.

Comment: I had to uninstall node/npm. Used brew to install NVM and then installed node using `nvm install node` then `sudo npm install -g typescript` to get `tsc --version` to work

Comment: I did only "npm install typescript -g" and it worked perfectly

Comment: Upgrading node-version helped me.

Comment: Installing tsc global helped me on Win10: "npm install -g tsc"

Comment: Had to upgrade node version for this to work correctly also, thanks!

Comment: use `yarn global add typescript` to install it globally with yarn.

Comment: Just in case someone encounters this on VS Code debug, you'd want to restart VS Code after setting/installing the right node version.

Comment: If this not is compatible with the last nodejs version and you don´t like upgrade nodejs version then install the corresponding version of typescript for your actual nodejs version, for example for mi 4.2.4 is good, `npm install typescript@4.2.4 --unsafe-perm=true`. Thanks

Answer (score 208):

You are all messing with the global installations and -path files. Just a little error might damage every project you have ever written, and you will spend the rest of the night trying to get a `console.log('hi')` to work again.

If you have run `npm i typescript --save-dev` in your project - just try to run:

```
npx tsc
```

And see if it works before messing with global stuff (unless of course you really know what you are doing)

Comment: Finally an answer without global installations

Comment: Agree, this should be the accepted answer!
To init a new npm package, run those 3 commands:
npm init -y && npm i typescript --save-dev && npx tsc --init

Comment: Thanks for taking into account global installations. Though I want to add that 'npx tsc foo.ts' is needed to compile TS to JS

Comment: Why does this work when `npm run tsc` and `npm tsc` do not work?

Answer (score 99):

I had to do this:

```
npx tsc app.ts
```

Comment: This helped me, but to clarify, I had to do `npm install --save-dev typescript && npx tsc --version && npx tsc <filename>`. This installed `tsc`, successfully tested it with `--version`, and successfully compiled my `ts` file to a `js` file.

Comment: This worked, but i just used `npx tsc`. Adding tsc probably resolves need to use npx.

Comment: Why is that some have to use 'tsc' with npx and for others it works without npx?

Answer (score 33):

After finding all solutions for this small issue for macOS only.
Finally, I got my TSC works on my MacBook pro.

This might be the best solution I found out.

For all macOS users, instead of installing TypeScript using NPM, you can install TypeScript using homebrew.

```
brew install typescript
```

Please see attached screencap for reference.
[image]

Comment: After 12 hours this works for me :) just following your post. Thank you so much @Marjun

Comment: This is what worked for me and not *npm i typescript -g* . Probably has to do with my path running through brew for nvm

Answer (score 19):

Globally installing TypeScript package worked for me.

```
npm install typescript -g
```

Answer (score 11):

If your TSC command is not found in MacOS after proper installation of TypeScript (using the following command: `$ sudo npm install -g typescript`, then ensure Node `/bin` path is added to the `PATH` variable in `.bash_profile`.

Open `.bash_profile` using terminal: $ open ~/.bash_profile;

Edit/Verify bash profile to include the following line (*using your favorite text editor*):

```
export PATH="$PATH:"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin"";
```

Load the latest bash profile using terminal: `source ~/.bash_profile`;

Lastly, try the command: `$ tsc --version`.

Answer (score 9):

For mac users, you don't need to restart your laptop or doing any other commands

Use `brew install typescript`

Answer (score 6):

First Install typescript by running this command `npm install typescript`
or `npm install -g typescript` [ for installing typescript globally ] then run `npx tsc --version` for checking version of Typescript, instead of `tsc --version`.

Same goes to running any typescript file, just run `npx tsc <filename>.ts`
For example, for a file named hello.ts, run `npx tsc hello.ts`.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is specific for iTermV2 on MAC

1. First of all, I needed to instal as `sudo` (admin) during NPM install

   sudo npm install -g typescript
2. NPM installs the libraries under `/usr/local/Cellar/node/<your latest version>/lib/node_modules/typescript` folder and symlinks at `/usr/local/Cellar/node/<your latest version>/bin/tsc`

hence I went ~/.zshrc ( .bashrc, if you use bash)and added `/usr/local/Cellar/node/<your latest version>/bin` to the $PATH.

3. reload the shell profile via `source ~/.zshrc` (.bashrc in your case)

Comment: Hm good to know. But who takes care of these links from now on?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
npm rebuild typescript
```

This will rebuild the `tsc` link on your machine.

Comment: This was what helped me after banging my head against multiple install/uninstalls of tsc...

Comment: I didn't want to fix the issue by installing typescript globally. This WORKED

Answer (score 4):

In package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run tsc"
  },
```

Works for me for Heroku deployment.
Installing typescript `npm install -D typescript` and writing tsc in the build script  `"build": "tsc",` does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem on Ubuntu 19.10 LTS.

To solve this I ran the following command:

```sh
$ sudo apt install node-typescript
```

After that, I was able to use `tsc`.

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix for Mac I found. Just run these commands:

```
sudo npm install -g concurrently
sudo npm install -g lite-server
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Nothing worked except this for me.

Comment: How does this answer have so many upvotes? Please don't do this. First of all, the first two packages have nothing to do with this problem and second of all, you should not be using `sudo` to install packages globally. Check the comment on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57119888/163799

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that work for me was put 
npx tsc -v
or for the compiling
npx tsc salida.ts

"salida.ts" is the name of the file

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your `npm` version
2. If it's not properly installed, then install it first
3. run this command `npm install typescript -g`
4. now `tsc <file_name>.ts`
5. It'll create a corresponding `.js` file. eg `<file_name>.js`
6. now  try `node <file_name>.js`

Answer (score 2):

For windows and yarn user, try `yarn tsc --init`

Answer (score 1):

None of above worked for me.

I tried this as well,

```
yum install typescript
```

was able to compile by hook and crook as follows. Not recommended but just a workaround.

Just install locally using `npm`, as `npm install typescript` and verify in node_module folder, if its downloaded. and then run,

```js
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc  --help
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc  //this line actually runs and compile and generate the compiled file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use sudo if you are using Linux.

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

### Non-admin solution

I do not have admin privileges since this machine was issued by my job.

- get path of where node modules are being installed **and** copy to clipboard

  - `npm config get prefix | clip`
  - don't have clip? just copy output from `npm config get prefix`
- add copied path to environment variables

  - **my preferred method (Windows)**
  - (Ctrl + R), paste `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`
  - under User Variables, double-click on **Path** > **New** > Paste copied path

Answer (score 0):

None of above answer solve my problem.
The fact is that my project did not have type script installed.
But locally I had run `npm install -g typescript`. So I did not notice that typescript node dependency was not in my package json.

When I pushed it to server side, and run `npm install`, then `npx tsc` I get a tsc not found. In facts remote server did not have typescript installed. That was hidden because of my local global typescript install.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 i solved it by adding `%APPDATA%\npm` to the path

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot to deploy the Node.js typescript project on Heroku and I have tried different solutions but none of them working for me. So, I have implemented a solution that is to create a build locally which is a **dist** folder, and just only push dist folder with package.json files, you don't need to push your **src** folder to Heroku. and in your script add **"start": "node dist/index.js"**

Here are my project structure:
[image: Here are my project structure:]

.gitignore file:
[image: .gitignore file:]

package.json file:

```
"start": "node dist/index.js",
"deploy": "tsc && git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku master",
"dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --pretty --transpile-only src/index.ts"
```

just need to add these scripts:
[image: just need to add these scripts:]

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this because I didn't want to globally install typescript. I found I had to add a script to the package.json that called tsc for me. The solution can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446584/6301243

Answer (score 0):

I apply many things but these two are the way which might be work for you:

- Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended)
- Manually change npm's default directory

Answer (score 0):

For **pnpm**:

I was using pnpm and the same error occurred to me, which I fixed using
`npx tsc index.js`

Answer (score 0):

One possible culprit to this could be having a typo in your dependency key at package.json, when running `yarn` in your monorepo root does not install `typescript`.
In my case I manually added a new lib to my monorepo and then tried to type "devDependencies" into package.json, but instead ended up with "devDependecies".

To fix this, install typescript from your terminal at your monorepo root:
`yarn workspace @myorg/mylib -D typescript`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install typescript globally before your script, something like as follows

Yml file sample

```
 script:
   - cd utils
   - npm install -g typescript
   - tsc ../utils/<your-script>.ts
   - node ../utils/<your-script>
```

Answer (score -1):

For windows:

Add the path by using command as below in command prompt:
path=%path%;C:\Users\\npm

As in my case, the above path was not registered for command.

%userprofile% in run windows, will give you path to C:\users\

Answer (score -1):

I solved this on my machine by just running `sudo npm install` in the directory that I was getting the error.

Comment: You shouldn't be forced to run `sudo` for installning packages. Then you should reinstall npm. See more [Do not sudo npm](https://givan.se/do-not-sudo-npm)

Answer (score -5):

This works perfectly on Mac. Tested on macOS High Sierra

```
sudo npm install -g concurrently
sudo npm install -g lite-server
sudo npm install -g typescript
tsc --init
```

This generates the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: `concurrently` and `lite-server` have little to nothing to do with being able to run the `tsc` command. Please do not advise installing unnecessary dependencies.