# How do I compile Typescript at Heroku postinstall?

Tags: typescript, heroku, compilation, tsc

Instead of uploading the precompiled dist directory, I want to compile src at server side instead.

Here are my scripts inside package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "postinstall": "tsc"
  }
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/pg": "^7.4.4",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.31",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "pg": "^7.4.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
```

Since 'npm install will add the node_modules/.bin folder to the PATH environment variable during installation', Heroku should be able to call it directly.

But here is the error I get:

```
Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > bilgi-yarismasi@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_afa42c7943d4b71d2b48a016ae3b9e50
       > tsc

       sh: 1: tsc: not found
       npm ERR! file sh
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno ENOENT
       npm ERR! syscall spawn
       npm ERR! bilgi-yarismasi@1.0.0 postinstall: `tsc`
       npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! Failed at the bilgi-yarismasi@1.0.0 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LTxbD/_logs/2018-02-25T10_36_06_374Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: You can also check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63104672/2404470)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to call `tsc` from an npm script. Otherwise Heroku tries to find a global dependency named `tsc`.

Create a new npm script in your `package.json`:

```
"tsc": "tsc"
```

now replace `"postinstall": "tsc"` with:

```
"postinstall": "npm run tsc"
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for saving my day, uhm _week_.

Comment: it's not working on bitbucket pipeline, how can i solve?

Comment: Probably it is missing TSC. Dev dependency only?

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz but `dev` dependency should still work, the doc says dev dependences are kept for the duration of install and build steps, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 10):

Typescript should be installed as a devdependency

have `web: node server.js`
in your procfile

make sure to add npm build as a postinstall script

Telling `npm` that typescript is installed locally will fix tsc not found issue, since npm is trying to find it globally on heroku.

like this.

```
"tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
"build": "tsc",
"postinstall": "npm run build",
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It is definitely better than the current marked correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Spent a while to deploy my simple typescript create-react-app to Heroku. Here what worked for me.

package.json - does not need postinstall at all

In the command line install buildpack for your application
run:
heroku buildpacks:add zidizei/typescript
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs

You can also search for buildpacks
run:
heroku buildpacks:search typescript

My server looks like that (/root/server.js)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.static('build'));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Also before pushing to heroku, do run 'npm run build'.

My solution wont work if you gonna use webpack dev server, it must be custom server, in my case it was EXPRESS.

Comment: The whole purpose we use post-install is to not to run the build script everytime we push the repo.

Answer (score 1):

just install typescript as dependency it will work

Comment: Typescript should be added as a dev dependency.

You only need to tell npm that typescript is installed locally

by adding this to your script

"tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",

Answer (score 0):

For me in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run tsc"
  },
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that I found viable for this problem:

1. **Move typescript from devDependencies to dependencies** object in your package.json
2. **Install a Heroku buildpack on your app which can run the ts command**. You can search Heroku buildpacks on elements.heroku.com. The procedure to add is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers here too to fix the `sh: 1: tsc: not found` error, but the only thing I could get to work was to move typescript from dev dependency to dependency.

Comment: You just need to not rely on `tsc` at runtime. As long as you build your application at build time and try to run plain JavaScript at runtime this won't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I installed typescript as devDependency
and in Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
//other scripts
"build": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
}
```