# How to know which typescript version running on angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript

So i did `ng -v` it shows me everything except typescript, so how can i check Typescript version of my angular 4 project.

Comment: Just look at the version in node_modules/typescript/package.json. This is applicable for any npm dependency

Comment: `ng -v` worked for me

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Open `package.json` file and check `devDependencies` node. It has typescript version used in project like below.

```
"typescript": "^2.4.0",
```

You can also use command prompt as Sajeetharan suggested in below answer.

Comment: Great.. let me know if you need any help.. You should mark answer as accepted if you find helpful.

Comment: although keep in mind the caret in ^2.4.0 means you could be getting 2.5.x 2.6.x, etc. It tells you the minor version will automatically be updated to the latest version upon a fresh install (or an npm update)

Comment: It's wrong to me, it doesn't give the actual version since you use a caret see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json The only reliable way to get the version as indicated in another answer is to check the resolved version not the asked version

Answer (score 56):

If you want the exact version installed as a package dependency use the `ls` command:

```
npm ls typescript
```

Alternatively, you could run `tsc` with the `-v` flag:

If installed locally:

```
node_modules\.bin\tsc -v
```

If installed globally:

```
tsc -v
```

NOTE: If you plan on checking package.json for the version number, keep in mind the caret in ^2.4.0 means you could be getting 2.4.x, 2.5.x 2.6.x, etc. The `^` tells you the minor version will automatically be updated to the latest version upon a fresh install or an `npm update`.

If the version number is preceeded by `~` (i.e. ~2.4.0), then the patch number is automatically updated on a new install or update. That means any of the following versions could be installed: 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, etc, but not 2.5.x

Comment: in side `node_modules\.bin` it shows The program 'tsc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install node-typescript.   show me same for globally i have ubuntu

Comment: to install it locally: `npm install typescript --save-dev`. To install it globally: `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Instead of `node_modules\.bin\tsc -v`, what about `npx tsc -v` ?

Answer (score 15):

Open command prompt , to check the globally installed version,

Type

```
tsc -v
```

and hit Enter

to check particular project version, navigate to **`node_modules\.bin\`**

```
./tsc -v
```

another way is to check the **`package.json`** inside the project folder

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: That will tell the version of the globally installed TypeScript compiler. Not the version used by angular-cli for that particular project.

Comment: @JBNizet yes right! usually we instlal typescript globallly

Comment: That will still tell the version of the globally installed tsc. You would need `./tsc -v` to be sure you're executing the local one.

Comment: *usually we instlal typescript globallly*: but angular-cli never uses your globally installed version. It uses the one specified in the devDependencies section of the package.json file of the project.

Answer (score 10):

To know the version of Typescript, use:

```
ng v
```

This will out put the typescript version and other dependence versions as well. Mine show as bellow:

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.1
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.1
@angular/cli                      6.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.1
@schematics/angular               0.7.1
@schematics/update                0.7.1
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Comment: This is what the OP tried to do and it didn't work. Could you please expand on alternatives if this doesn't work?

Comment: If  `ng -v` didn't work, then it is probably that typescript is not installed. So install typescript as follows: `npm install -g typescript` for more information see the linke [https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript]

Comment: ng v is the command, not -v. This also just reports what is installed, not what is working with a particular Angular version.

Answer (score 7):

In my ubuntu 18.04 LTS with angular 7 cli installed, I typed

```
ng v
```

and it gave the output:

```
Node: 11.8.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.3
@angular/cli                      7.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.3
@schematics/angular               7.2.3
@schematics/update                0.12.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.28.4
```

Answer (score 4):

Just type on terminal:

```
npm ls typescript
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer using yarn (since other answer were using npm)

This will list the dependencies using yarn then filter only typescript

```
yarn list --pattern typescript
```

Or you can simply check the content of yarn.lock file (equivalent of package-lock.json)

```
grep "typescript" yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the typescript version which is installed on my machine, use this command in command prompt.

> tsc --version

Comment: It means typescript is not installed on your machine, if installed then this command would give the version,

Comment: I didn't asked for my machine, I asked for Angular project :(