# Using pm2 with changed npm's default directory

Tags: npm, pm2, tsc

I develop node.js application on typescript, and I want to deploy app to the server with `pm2 deploy`.
I don't have sudo access on the server, so i can't just install npm packages globally.
According to [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory), i've changed my npm's default directory to `~/.npm-global` and install typescript globally with `npm i -g typescript`.
My ecosystem.config.js deploy section looks like:

```
deploy: {
    production: {
        'user': "user",
        'host': "example.com",
        'repo': "https://github.com/username/repo.git",
        'path': "/home/projects/project/",  
        'post-deploy': "npm install && tsc && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production"
    }
}
```

When I run `tsc` on server througt ssh it works, but when I run `pm2 deploy production update`, it says:

```
bash: tsc: command not found
post-deploy hook failed
```

I also tried NVM, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404922/tsc-command-not-found-in-compiling-typescript