# Deploy to Node App Azure App Service tsc not recognized as command

Tags: azure-web-app-service, npm-start

I am trying to deploy a nodejs app onto Azure App Service.  I did the basics of deploying it, but it's failing to run.  It seems it is designed to run "node run.js" commands rather than "npm run start".

I'm playing in the console, and if I try to run `npm run start` manually, I get a series of errors tied to build.  Basically:

```
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I'm wondering if there's something really obvious here about how tsc (and others) can be added to path.  I have to admit, I'm not particularly well versed in using Azure or Node for that matter.  Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thanks!

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test-scraper",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:dev": "tsc --watch",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start": "pm2 start dist/src/main.js --node-args=\"-r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js\" && pm2 monit",
    "stop": "pm2 delete main"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.8",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "discord-webhook-node": "^1.1.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "messaging-api-telegram": "^1.0.1",
    "playwright-firefox": "^1.4.2",
    "pm2": "^4.5.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: If my answer not help, please post your `package.json` content for checking.

Comment: Just added, thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command locally for installing typescript, because your code is compiled with the tsc command.

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Mostly I was following this [tutorial](http://www.codefoster.com/tscazure/).

Add the tsc command to package.json and add the dependencies:

```
"build": "tsc --project ./"
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
```

Here is my file structure:

[image]

I add a empty `file.ts` and add this scripts to the `tsconfig.jason` file:

```
"exclude": [ "src", "wwwroot" ],
  "include": [ "file.ts" ]
```

Deploy through Azure Web App deployment center:
[image]

And the app build (`tsc`) run successfully:
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I tried to command, but I get a series of errors:
`npm ERR! 404  'typsecript@latest' is not in the npm registry.`
Is this because the app service can't access the internet?  I'm thinking in AWS terms where I have to grant permissions for the internet.

Comment: Yes, you need to access the internet. Another reason might be you need upgrade your `npm` version.

Comment: I hate to ask since I feel like I'm asking to be spoonfed, but where would I handle permissions to install npm packages through the console available on the portal?  I was googling for 15 minutes without anything remotely promising.  Sorry :(

Comment: Okay, I will edit my answer step by step for deploying a web app with this command.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think the more sane way to go about this is to just dockerize and push it out that way instead.  Again thanks a ton, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

if you are deploying to `Production` (NODE_ENV: production), `devDependencies` will no longer being installed, and you need to edit your `package.json` and move `typescript` to `dependencies`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337513/3183592)