# Why the command tsc <filename.ts> just runs using npx tsc <filename.ts>?

Tags: typescript, npm

I was having a problem with tsc command. Then I saw here ['tsc command not found' in compiling typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404922/tsc-command-not-found-in-compiling-typescript) that I could use `npx tsc app.ts` and it worked. Could anyone explain to me why just `tsc app.ts` didn't work ? The error message was 'tsc command not found' and my TypeScript version is 3.8.3

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Solve this by installing TypeScript globally:

```
[sudo] npm i -g typescript
```

…or keep the same behaviour as explained by @strdr4605 since it works.

Comment: I had installed TypeScript globally with ``npm -g typescript`` but I just made it again using the command that you suggested ``npm i -g typescript`` and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From `npx` [docs](https://github.com/npm/npx#description):

> Executes `<command>` either from a local node_modules/.bin, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for `<command>` to run.

So if `typescript` is not installed globally or locally the `npx` first will download it and then run the `tsc` binary.