# This is not the tsc command you are looking for

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc

When I run `tsc` in the terminal (it does not matter where) I get returned:

```
$ npx tsc --version

                This is not the tsc command you are looking for


To get access to the TypeScript compiler, tsc, from the command line either:

- Use npm install typescript to first add TypeScript to your project before using npx
- Use yarn to avoid accidentally running code from un-installed packages
```

I do not have TypeScript installed globally to my knowledge so what I am expecting is that it can't find `tsc`.

Comment: Did you run `which tsc`(or the equivalent Windows command) to see what tsc is being executed?

Comment: `where.exe tsc` says `C:\Users\hjort\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc`, thank you for pointing out the obvious as it helped me fix the issue.

Comment: `npm install typescript` or `yarn add typescript` should fix it

Comment: Found this as a solution in Mac os for me... if it helps you anyhow https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360373/4715998

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had installed the old typescript compiler https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc by mistake.

running `where.exe tsc` to find out what I was actually running suggested by @siddharth made me find the issue

Answer (score 72):

The problem in my case was that I had installed `tsc` package instead of the correct `typescript`. From https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc:

> Use `typescript` to get access to the `tsc` CLI command.

The fix is:

```
npm uninstall tsc
npm install -D typescript
```

Commands like `npx tsc --version` will still run because `typescript` provides the `tsc` executable.

Comment: yep.. you need to install `typescript` package and not the `tsc`

Comment: The fix is actually `npm uninstall tsc` and then `npm install typescript` (even if it was installed before, because during `tsc` uninstall the file `node_modules/.bin/tsc` gets removed no matter which package is was installed from).

Answer (score 26):

On my Mac, this fixed it:

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
npm install -g typescript
```

When I was fooling around trying to get started, i had done something like this:

```
npm install -g tsc   #bad, don't do this
```

which had screwed up my install.

Comment: Worked great on my Windows PC when the others didn't. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well on my Mac. Thx.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing to do as it's a very easy problem.
Go to your vs code folder where you have installed node package.
For example, in my system, it is:

*`C:\Users\vivekranjan\AppData\Roaming\npm`*

First of all you will notice that both the tscServer and tsc files are not created. So first delete all the tsc files, then go to the vs code and uninstall typeScript like this:

```
npm uninstall typescript
```

Then again install the typescript like this:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: For me, installing typescript with -g helped.

Answer (score 7):

if You are getting [tsc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677320/this-is-not-the-tsc-command-you-are-looking-for) *command error* just run it on your terminal

```html
 npm install -g typescript --force
```

Answer (score 6):

The [tsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc) module is DEPRECATED! You only need the [typescript module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), if you need tsc!

Install the typescript module by:

```
npm install -D typescript
```

Answer (score 5):

This solved the issue for me:

```
npm uninstall typescript
npm uninstall tsc #local tsc package
npm install typescript -g
```

Answer (score 3):

With `typescript` already installed both as a `devDependency` and globally, for me the solution was updating a `package.json` script:

Before:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pnpx tsc ..."
  }
}
```

After:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc ..."
  }
}
```

Perhaps everyone else knew that `p/npx` is not needed in `scripts`, but I didn't.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I avoid installing global dependencies, to keep my environment clean and deterministic.

=> I prefer to fix this problem by specifying the package that npx must use:

```bash
$ npx --package typescript tsc --version
```

Comment: ❤️‍❤️‍❤️‍

Answer (score 1):

1. First Run `npm uninstall tsc`, it will remove all the .bin/tcs folder.
2. Then Run `npm install typescript`, it will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the npm uninstall step, even after doing npm remove.

Answer (score 1):

I have to uninstall `tsc` from my package.json. It was not supposed to be there; the `typescript` lib is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try chocolatey manager for typescript installation
https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/typescript

```
choco install typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Volta or similar version managers you can do

```sh
npm remove -g typescript tic
pnpm remove -g typescript (if using pnpm)
```

and install it again with your node package manager of choice (globally)!

Answer (score 0):

tsc is `typescript/bin/tsc`, so must `uninstall tsc` first.
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUK0o.png

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would ask you to share "code" or "output" as text here and not as image

Answer (score 0):

in my mac it worked only after adding 'force' flag to the command:

```
npm uninstall -g typescript --force
npm install -g typescript --force
```

Answer (score 0):

go to `tsc.cmd` or `tsc.ps1` path

look likes this

```
node_module
  typescript // remove this
  other...
tsc.cmd // remove this
other...
```

then

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I did `which tsc` then `rm -rf /[path]`.

WORKED!!!! Finally

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by deleting the `node_modules` folder, and re-running `yarn install`.