# when i try to run this cmd npm install -g tsc im getting this error [Error: EACCES: permission denied]

Tags: javascript, typescript

My main goal is to convert ts code to js, and when I tried npm install -g tsc, I received the following error:

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsc' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.tsc-8BsQC1RP'

I tried to run as admin, like sudo npm install -g tsc, then I installed without failing. I thought issue got resolved, then I ran tsc cmd again and got an error.

saying :This is not the tsc command you are looking for To get access to the TypeScript compiler, tsc, from the command line either:

- Use npm install typescript to first add TypeScript to your project before using npx
- Use yarn to avoid accidentally running code from un-installed packages

I want to convert ts files to js

Comment: Duplicate of [This is not the tsc command you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677320/this-is-not-the-tsc-command-you-are-looking-for)

Answer (score 0):

[The `tsc` package on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc) is a deprecated package.

Per the `README` in the linked NPM listing, install `typescript` instead "*to get access to the `tsc` CLI command*".

```
npm install -g typescript
```