# I installed type script globally with npm on my mac and it not working

Tags: macos, npm, node-modules, tsc

Ive tried to install TS globally on my mac with the command npm install typescript -g
also tried this with the "sudo" before, its looks like it working but then when i trying to look up my tsc version in the terminal, I get this error zsh: command not found: tsc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mac, instead of NPM, install typescript with:

```
brew install typescript
```

(Also if you want to make the `npm i -g typescript` work, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061934/4718434) to add the globally installed packages to the PATH)

Also make sure to install the proper ts extensions for your IDE.

Comment: Thank you it works, but i have another problem, when Im working on my angular project i don't get error in the html file before Im saving the file, however i do get errors in the TS files

Comment: Update, the issue was that I didn't enable the Angular Language Services extension. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: @DrorHandler Hey. Sorry for late reply, i just saw your prev comment. Glad it's fixed. Happy codding <3