# tsc command cannot be found in Git Bash

Tags: typescript, git-bash

I'm having issues with running tsc command on Git Bash, however it does work on Command Prompt. How can I fix such issue?

Here is the error:
`C:\Users\grant\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

I tried to reinstall NodeJS, Gitbash and following this ['tsc command not found' in compiling typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404922/tsc-command-not-found-in-compiling-typescript)

Didn't apply any effect in solving the problem.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to change the Path variable with Variable Environment. I first tried to run tsc file with full path, and simply put it into PATH variables.