# How to use Typescript 'tsc' command as a devDependency?

Tags: typescript, dependencies, node-modules, tsc

Seems like I'm having a problem with whats supposed to be very simple, I want to have `typescript` as a `devDependency` in my project and not global.

Ive installed it using `npm i --save-dev typescript`, but i cannot seem to be able to run `tsc` command to produce my `javascript` files.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

I've tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030078/how-to-install-and-run-typescript-locally-in-npm#) question but couldn't find any solution there..

I understand simply running `tsc` in my terminal cannot possibly work as it is not installed globally and is not a known command, but what IS the way?

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: The `npm run tsc` approach that is described in one of the answers in your linked question should work.

Comment: @Matthias247 thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately adding this script does not work

Answer (score 2):

standalone tsc command is available only for global installation.
When you install it as a devDependency you have to use it with npx before the tsc command like so:
npx tsc -v

The reason for this can be found here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/download

It is also good to understand difference between npm and npx commands.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to define a script inside your `package.json` like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"
}
```

To run it: `npm run start`

Because you added typescript to your devDependencies, this should always be available.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately, doing as you suggest does not solve the problem. i even tried running it manually from within the typescript package.. any idea why? npm just throws the most generic error saying exit status 1

Comment: Your error is most likely coming from somewhere else and not from running TSC. Can you provide the detailed error output/trace?