# tsc command not recognized window command

Tags: typescript

I have installed  typescript globally, when i am running tsc -v. i am getting below error
Please advise how to resolve this issue
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tsc is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369501/tsc-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Install type script globally as

```
> npm i -g typescript
```

If you are using windows then after installation you can check this folder  for **tsc** command file **C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm**

If still the **tsc** command doesn't work in terminal, then add the path **C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm**  in environment variables.

Comment: under  c:\users\nv       appDat\Roaming\npm  folder not available

Comment: @NareshV appData folder default setting is hidden