# How to configure VS Code to use TypeScript already installed

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am getting started with TypeScript and have it installed here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`

[image: TS installation and versions]

When I try to run `tsc`VS Code gives this error:

[image]

How to configure VS Code to use one of the versions in there to compile using `tsc`?
Any version will do fine.

Is there no option other than re-installing using npm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install tsc - npm globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have tsc in your PATH. If you installed Typescript through Node locally, check this SO post: [tsc is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369501/tsc-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command/47898735). Otherwise, open System Properties and go to Path Variables to set up your PATH ([instructions](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)).